# How to find an element in std::map with structures that has at least one data member equal to the key

Tags: c++, struct, stdmap

I have a question about how to find the corresponding element which has at least one data number equal to the key being searched in a `std::map` with structures.

For example, suppose that I am to find the phone number of a person with his name **or** id in a phonebook (let's assume there's no name that are used more than one person), I will declare a `struct` named `Person` and define a `std::map` containing `Person` objects and his/her phone number (in `std::string`):

```cpp
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string id;
};

std::map<Person, std::string> phonebook;
```

As I searched from the Internet, I have known that the struct needs overloaded `==` and `<` operators to work with `std::map` and implemented them:

```cpp
bool operator==(const Person &person1, const Person &person2) {
    return person1.name == person2.name || person1.id == person2.id;
}

bool operator<(const Person &person1, const Person &person2) {
    return person1.id < person2.id;
}
```

I used logical "or" (`||`) in the overloaded `==` operator in order to implement the feature that the phone number can be found with a person's name **or** id, instead of needing both.

I wrote some code to test the feature:

```cpp
// Add some entries
phonebook[{"Jack", "001"}] = "12345";
phonebook[{"Mike", "002"}] = "12346";
phonebook[{"Eric", "003"}] = "12347";

// Search by name
std::map<Person, std::string>::iterator iter = phonebook.find({"Jack", ""});
if (iter == phonebook.end())
    std::cout << "Cannot find the phone number for Jack" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Jack's phone number is " << iter->second << std::endl;

// Search by id
iter = phonebook.find({"", "001"});
if (iter == phonebook.end())
    std::cout << "Cannot find the phone number for 001" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "001's phone number is " << iter->second << std::endl;
```

However, I found that searching by id works very well, but searching by name cannot work. No matter what name is being searched, the phone number can never be found. The code for test above produced the following output:

```
Cannot find the phone number for Jack
001's phone number is 12345
```

while the expected output is

```
Jack's phone number is 12345
001's phone number is 12345
```

What's more, if I change the way I implement the overloaded `<` operator to

```cpp
bool operator<(const Person &person1, const Person &person2) {
    return person1.name < person2.name; // change "id" to "name"
}
```

then searching by name works well, but searching by id will not work.

So how can I implement the feature (to find one's phone number with his/her name **or** id) with `std::map`? Or is it cannot be implemented in such a way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (or other *functor*)?

Comment: Use two maps, one for each key you want to look up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` is defined only in terms of the `operator<`. Two map entries are considered equal if and only if `!(a < b)` and `!(b < a)`. Your `operator==` is not helping here, and all the `find()` call is doing is finding the person with the ID you specified (or name in the second case) because it only considers `operator<`.

The bigger picture is that `std::map::find` makes use of the sortedness of `std::map` (generally implemented as a red black tree) to avoid having to check each element. This property is not helpful if both name and ID participate in your search, because you can't tell if a matching name *or* is before or after any given node in the tree - you only know that for the ID (or, in the second case, the name).

Unless you want to implement a *very* fancy and complex way of combining the name and ID into a single sortable/searchable field (no idea how you would do that), you will have to check each element. `std::find_if` does that for you:

```
std::find_if(phonebook.begin(), phonebook.end(), [name, id](const std::pair<Person, std::string>& personAndNumber) {
  const Person& person = personAndNumber.first;
  return person.name == name || person.id == id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Max Langhof pointed out, you can only use `find()` to search for **keys** in a map as maps are sorted on key. To search using value (name in your case), you can use simply iterate over all the keys. Though this approach is not efficient as  you have to search through each record in the map.

```
for (auto it = phonebook.begin(); it != phonebook.end(); it++)
{
    if (it->second == "001")
    {
        return it->first;
    }     
}

// If you reach here, then value was not found
std::cout << "Cannot find the phone number for 001" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and personally if I iterate through the container to search, I think `std::vector` may be a better choice. :-)

Comment: @YangHanlin I agree that vector would be good in this case where we are anyways traversing through all nodes (in worst case). But then you will lose the advantage of finding the value by key. Since in your case you require search by both key and value, atleast you could be better off with map (atleast one parameter can be searched in O(log n) time complexity).